# didReceiveRemoteNotification not working in the background

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on a big app with a huge chunk of legacy code.
Currently - there's an implementation for:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

The problem is that it is only called when the app is in the foreground OR when the user taps the the notification while the app is in the background.
I tried to implement:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

But the app behaves the same.
In any case - this method is not called when the app is in the background.
What could be the problem?

Comment: It's normal that the method won't be called when app is in the background. System will notify you the notification through prompting a alert view or a banner.

Comment: What's the iOS version of your device? Is it at least 7? Because `fetchCompletionHandler:` requires minimum iOS 7.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Implementing `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is the correct way, but you also need to do the following:

Make sure to register for remote notifications, see [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623010-registerforremotenotificationtyp):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    return YES;
}
```

Also make sure to edit `Info.plist` and check the "Enable Background Modes" and "Remote notifications" check boxes:

[image]

Additionally, you need to add `"content-available":1` to your push notification payload, otherwise the app won't be woken if it's in the background (see [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) *updated*):

> For a push notification to trigger a download operation, the
> notification’s payload must include the content-available key with its
> value set to 1. When that key is present, the system wakes the app in
> the background (or launches it into the background) and calls the app
> delegate’s
> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
> method. Your implementation of that method should download the
> relevant content and integrate it into your app

So payload should at least look like this:

```
{
    aps = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        sound : ""
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm already calling registerForRemoteNotificationTypes and Remote Notifications is enabled

Comment: @godmoney See my update answer, you need to add `"content-available":"1"` to your notification payload...

Comment: @BarisAkar Great.  I did not know about `content-available` payload. +1

Comment: I am enabled Background mode for remote notifications and Payload should contain content-available:1 key-value pair But not call my background method

Comment: @priyankagautam Sorry, but I don't know, what could cause your problem. Everything you need to do is actually described in this answer...

Comment: what if I didn't want to call `didReceiveRemoteNotification` when I launch the app by icon?

Comment: For those who are looking for this in new Xcode interface, take a look at your target -> Capabilities tab -> Background modes -> On

Comment: @BarisAkar the link in the answer is broken. Could you help fix it?

Comment: That did it. 1+

Comment: Without "sound": "" -> Thanks @onmyway133 It saved me..... iOS 10 its working fine... But not working on iOS 11, Any suggestions?

Comment: Not Info.plist but Capabilities there you can add Background Modes

Comment: The same issue is occurring for iOS 14. `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method never gets called when app is in background(not force close). Any suggestion for this? I followed the exact procedure and added "content-available" : 1 in the aps. `didReceiveRemoteNotification` only gets called in foreground.

Comment: I *thought* I had this problem because the notification wasn't arriving immediately. Then I decided to wait, and wait, and wait. Over a full minute after receiving the "banner" notification while my app was in the background, my app delegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification method was called. No idea why it's taking so long, and I had to make a minor change to improve the UX.

Comment: Came back to add that the long delay in receiving the notification in the background was only with APNS Sandbox environment. The notification to Prod is very quick.

Answer (score 17):

1. Register for push notification in app delegate.
2. Add background mode in app capabilities.
3. Add "content-available"="1" while sending the push notification(if you are using firebase replace "content-available"="1" by "content_available"="true" while sending the push notification from server side).

Comment: You do need "content-available"="1" for Firebase as well.  Doing "content_available"="true" doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Notification banner appeared, but -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: method was not called. The solution for me that worked was to add implementation of - application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method and forward call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler::

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo) { (UIBackgroundFetchResult) in

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ZaEem, have you found any solution

Comment: when the app is the background, sending a remote push notification only this method is called `func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])`

Comment: @UsmanNisar I have added the workaround for my problem and its working fine for me. is it not working for you ?

Answer (score 3):

I am creating an iOS project that will use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to deliver custom data elements, sent via Firebase/APNS notifications, from a company server to the iOS device.

The first thing I had to understand is that unlike Android, there is no similar type of 'Service' that will be able to capture and save information I'm sending, regardless if the app is in the foreground (active), background (still in memory) or not active (not in memory). Therefore, I have to use Notification messages NOT Data messages like I had designed for Android.

After much reading to understand both Apple APNS and the Firebase interface between the iOS app and APNS server, looking at countless posts on stackoverflow and other web resources, I finally figured out how to get this to work for my requirements.

When a Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Notification message is sent from the server (or Firebase Console as the FCM defaults to Notification NOT Data messages), it is delivered via APNS and presented as a notification on the iOS device. When the user taps on the notification banner, iOS does the following: if the app is not running/loaded iOS launches the app, if the app is loaded/running but in the background iOS brings the app to the foreground OR if the app is in the foreground (all three cases), the message content is then delivered via func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {}.

One thing for sure, you Must Enable Background Modes and check Remote Notification, you DO NOT have to include {"content-available" : 1} in the payload.

1) Go through the APNS and Firebase setup, pretty straight forward, generate and register certificates and such.

2) In appDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, add:

```
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self as? MessagingDelegate

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        }
        else {

            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)

            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

3) Then add these call back functions to appDelegate:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {

            print("\n*** application - didReceiveRemoteNotification - fetchCompletionHandler - Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print("\n*** application - didReceiveRemoteNotification - full message - fetchCompletionHandler, userInfo: \(userInfo)")

        myNotificationService?.processMessage(title: userInfo["Title"] as! String
            , text: userInfo["Text"] as! String, completion: { (success) in

                if success {
                    completionHandler(.newData)
                }
                else {
                    completionHandler(.noData)
                }
        })
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
```

Very Helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html

Answer (score 1):

My device was in a bad state. I had to restart the device to get it working although I had done all the pre-requisites mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

There is another scenario that most of the replies are not identifying and the docs are not mentioning either.

In my case, I had my device configured with a special uncommon/unrelated setting.

Go to Settings -> General -> Background App Refresh

You are presented with 3 options:

1. Off
2. Wi-Fi
3. Wi-Fi Cellular Data

!***IMPORTANT***!
There are a viral videos on social network recommending setting this to "Off" or "Wi-Fi" in order to save battery life / data plan.
Thats when I set this to "OFF", and didReceiveRemoteNotification was never being called in the background, but strangely enough it was called once I opened the app.

Even if you have it on "Wi-Fi / Cellular Data", if you don't have internet, it wont be called (duhh), but most important, I think the guides should recommend having this small detail covered in case there are users that fall in the "condition" of having this set to "Off" or "Wi-Fi" and being on Cellular network <- this is more common case.

The conditional for this can be retrieved at: UIApplication.shared.backgroundRefreshStatus

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622994-backgroundrefreshstatus

And the funny thing is that it will mess up your logic once the device is in low-power mode, because it will automatically change the status to "Off".

There is nowhere to find that this impacts notifications arriving when app is in background mode, so thats odd.
Anyways, hope this helps
-roberto

Answer (score 1):

**test it on a real device!!**

After spending hours trying all the answers posted here I decided to test it on a real device (it didn't work on the simulator) and it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by adding two methods one for tap and one for foreground in appDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult)
                 -> Void) {
    print(">>>NOTIF RECEIVED: ACTION:\(userInfo["action"] ?? "nil") DATA: \(userInfo["data"] ?? "nil")<<<")
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
    
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    print(">>>TAP NOTIF RECEIVED: ACTION:\(userInfo["action"] ?? "nil") DATA: \(userInfo["data"] ?? "nil")<<<")
    completionHandler()
}
```

Important Prerequisites:

- in`yourTarget/Signing&Capabilities` add `background modes` and check `remote notifications`
- check that initialize done before, in appDelegate/didfinishLaunchingWithOptions like this:

  ```
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: { _, _ in }
    )

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using `iOS 14` and I did everything from the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31450953/4833705) but nothing. I needed the `userInfo` from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` but it would never get called from the **background** even when I would press the actual notification. I had to use the below method and inside that method I use `UIApplication.shared.applicationState` to check for the background state. I get the `userInfo` from there.

```
// called when notification is tapped
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let dict = userInfo as? [String: Any] {

        let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
        if state == .inactive || state == .background {
                
                print("app is in BACKGROUND - userInfo: ", dict) // do something with dict when app is in the background and user taps the notification
                
        } else {
                
                print("app is in FOREGROUND - userInfo: ", dict) // do something with dict when app is in the foreground and user taps the notification
        }
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

Assuming you have everything else setup correctly, when you tap the notification while the app is in the **background**,  you will get the correct print statement with the `userInfo`.