# I can't get push notifications to appear in alert or banner form

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have registered for remote notifications
  fine

I have the deviceToken, the server is using it, it's sending messages to my test user, and when the app is in foreground I breakpoint and receive incoming remote notifications.

But when the app is backgrounded, nothing.

SSL certs signed for dev and prod. Currently, I using the dev push.pem with sandboxed APNS address, against a iOS Developer signed profile.

Help?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31450953/594074

Comment: possible duplicate of [didReceiveRemoteNotification not working in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450403/didreceiveremotenotification-not-working-in-the-background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions but the problem has been resolved, it was an issue with the server payload

1 Our server is using a third party push notification library
2 this library was wrapping our json payload

Our payload

> aps: { 
>    alert: ...,

With another layer

> aps: {
>    alert: {
>     aps: {
>      alert: ...,

Apple's APNs wasn't complaining one bit because the json is not malformed and totally legitimate and within size

I found this out after looking at the incoming notifications, while my iphone was run from/connected to Xcode.

Human error, server side

Answer (score 3):

Set the "Remote Notification" on in your app Capabilities as shown in the figure below:

[image: Remote Notification]

Hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Do as @karlos Suggest.
And also add  `"content-available":1`  in your payload because by providing this key with a value of 1 will indicate that new content is available. Including this key and value means that when your app is launched in the background or resumed, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` 
is called.

For more information follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) link.