# How to handle remote push notifications in background?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I want to download data when receiving a push notification while the app is not active.

I enabled push notifications in background mode.

This is my code :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    println("App is alive !!!")
    downloadData(){
        (success:Bool) -> Void in
        println("data downloaded : \(success)")
        var result = success ? UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData : UIBackgroundFetchResult.Failed
        completionHandler(result)
    }
}
```

I launch the app in debug mode, I leave it. I receive a push notification. The data is not downloaded.

I don't even know if the the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` has been called.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you implemented the backgroundhandler/expirationhandler for the event?

Comment: I don't know about this. Could you explain it ?

Comment: Check this out...http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial

Comment: _I don't even know if the the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` has been called._ What about this line: `println("App is alive !!!")`? Does it get printed or not? First make sure, if your callback is called or not.

Comment: Nothing prints on the console

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31450953/594074) to make sure the callback gets called...