# How to add content_available to Firebase Notification Composer

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to receive Firebase push notification in background on iOS device, using notification composer. As I see it is impossible without adding "content_available" : true to aps payload as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450403/didreceiveremotenotification-not-working-in-the-background).

In notification composer there is advanced options -> custom data, but writing "content_available" : true there includes it not into "aps", but in the whole received data.

How to make it appear in the aps?

Answer (score 0):

If there is someone wondering as well, as answered on GitHub by Firebase, this is impossible. Use HHTTP protocol or one of the Admin SDKs.

I ended up using Postman - pretty easy and you can include all the keys this way :)