# Firebase Notification Composer: How to set notification priority to "high"?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, react-native-firebase

As you know, notifications with low-priority does not trigger `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in iOS when app is in background state. I can trigger didReceiveRemoteNotification via using firebase admin rest api via specifying `content-available: true` and specifying priority as high, but when sending notification from Notification Composer since there is no such option to set priority, no event is emitted. Is there any way to send high priority notification from composer?  Btw I am aware of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299142/how-to-add-content-available-to-firebase-notification-composer) and it says that it is kinda impossible, but still, I guess there should be some workaround to achieve this `high-priority` feature in notification composer. Thanks in advance!

I expect to be able to send `high-priority` notification from FCM Notification Composer so it triggers `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in iOS

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Notifications sent from the composer are always high priority.